# C : How to shorten a string at the first letter

Tags: c, string

here's my problem:
I want to shorten a string, but at the beginning. For example "string" should be "tring" or "help"should become "elp".
It only needs to be the first letter.

Any ideas?
Thanks! =)

Comment: Put the code you have tried in your question please, so we can take a look at it! :)

Answer (score 8):

Either

```
string++;  /* Updates the pointer. */
```

or (assuming `string` is in writable memory)

```
memmove(string, string+1, strlen(string));  /* Updates memory, including NUL character. */
```

Comment: Second idea will give you undefined behaviour if `string` was declared as a literal.

Answer (score 2):

```
char* string = "hello";
char* string2 = string + 1;
printf("%s\n", string2); //prints "ello"
```

Comment: But don't do like this: `string = string + 1`, besause it's a memory leak in case if you allocate memory for string dynamically. If you need to get a copy of string, you can use `strdup`: `char* string2 = strdup(string + 1)`

Comment: @HannahAround I would prefer Lars solution. And be careful with `strdup`!

Comment: What happens to string2 after you free string and that memory gets reallocated to something else? string2 now contains random garbage (and may no longer be null terminated).

Comment: @Mawg I know, and I don't offer to free memory while you still need to use `string2`.

Comment: The point is that when you assignone pointer to another, they both point to the same area of memry - you did not make a copy of the string. If one changes it, it is changed for both, and if one frees the memory then it is freed for both, but the other doesn't know that, so if the meory is allocated elsewhere, the other guy is now pointing at that.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Dynamically allocated memory**
If you're prepared to keep the original string around (for the purposes of releasing any memory), you can use

```
char* foo = string + 1;
```

But you *must* keep the original pointer around in order to release the memory. `foo - 1` *does* recover the original pointer but is ugly.

You could also move the string contents back one place in memory but that will be O(N), but at least you're not changing pointer values so the performance loss might be worth the gain in program stability. Don't even *think* about using `strcpy` as that only works if the memory is disjoint: use `memmove` instead.

**2. Read-only literal**
If the string came about via something like `const char* string = "hello";` then you can define

```
const char* foo = string + 1;
```

which will *not* leak memory.

Answer (score 1):

str2 = strcpy(str2, &str[1]);

or

str2 = strncpy(str2, &str[1], strlen(str) - 1);

Comment: `strcpy` may not handle overlapping strings.

Comment: Sorry, I hit the enter key before I was finished. It's all better now :-)

Comment: @Mawg the restriction applying to `strcpy` applies to `strncpy`, too.

Comment: `str[1]` is a character.  Use either `str + 1` or `&str[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conserve memory, you may want to try using `memmove(3)` like so:

```
char *string = "Hello\0";
memmove(string, string + 1, strlen(string));
```

this will move "ello\0" into the place where "Hello" was before.  Thus you only use the same memory space, and do not use any extra.